# List users of specific role instead of removing them with specific role

Tags: user-roles, array, users

I am currently listing all the users except users with administrator role on custom page template with:

```
<?php
    $allUsers = get_users('orderby=post_count&order=DESC');
    $users = array();

    foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
    {
        if(!in_array( 'administrator', $currentUser->roles ))
        {
            $users[] = $currentUser;
        }
    }
?>
```

In the following format:

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) { ?>
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="avatar">
            <?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, '150' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="profileInfo">
            <h2 class="name"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h2>
            <p class="descrption"><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'description', true); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

As I am going to add 6 more custom user group (role) so I would like to list users from specific role instead of listing all the users except administrator role.

I have already tried several tutorial but for reason I am not able to incorporate with my current listing code.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you wish to display separate lists of users for each user role?

Comment: @engelen I want to list only users having subscriber role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch users from a specific role, you can use the `role` parameter of the [`get_users`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function. Each role has a specific ID; for WordPress' native roles, these are `administrator`, `editor`, `author`, `contributor` and `subscriber`. In your case, you would want to fetch only `subscriber` users:

```
$allUsers = get_users( array(
    'orderby' => 'post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'role' => 'subscriber'
) );
```

Comment: If I use `role` parameter of the `get_users` function I will have to comment out `if(!in_array( 'administrator', $currentUser->roles )) { }` from old `foreach` loop right?

Comment: Yes — even though the functionality stay the same, as none of the users has the administrator role anyway.